# Correlated Subquery in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following 2 tables for which I have to check the existence of values between them using a **correlated** sub-query.

The requirement is - for each record in the `orders` table check if the corresponding `custid` is present in the `customer` table, and then output a field (named `FLAG`) with value `Y` if the `custid` exists, otherwise `N` if it doesn't.

orders:

```
orderid | custid
12345   | XYZ
34566   | XYZ
68790   | MNP
59876   | QRS
15620   | UVW
```

customer:

```
id | custid
1  | XYZ
2  | UVW
```

Expected Output:

```
orderid | custid  | FLAG
12345   | XYZ     | Y
34566   | XYZ     | Y 
68790   | MNP     | N
59876   | QRS     | N
15620   | UVW     | Y
```

I tried something like the following but couldn't get it to work -

```
select 
o.orderid,
o.custid,
case when o.custid EXISTS (select 1 from customer c on c.custid = o.custid)
     then 'Y'
     else 'N'
end as flag
from orders o
```

Can this be solved with a **correlated scalar** sub-query ? If not what is the best way to implement this requirement ?

Please advise.

*Note: using Spark SQL query v2.4.0*

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for upvoting my answer. I have now tested that it works with a locally recreated copy of your data. Would you please accept my answer if it worked for you? I'm relatively new to StackOverflow like you, and every point counts! Thank you!

Comment: @Lars Skaug thanks for your response. Your solution works great and i have accepted the answer. However, just want to know if it is any way possible to do the same with the `EXISTS` clause/`correlated subquery` (for my understanding) ?

Comment: Maybe in the future. You can do this in Oracle, for instance. When you try it in spark 2.4, you actually get an informative error saying “ IN/EXISTS predicate sub-queries can only be used in a filter in Spark.” Informative although it’s not what you hoped for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IN/EXISTS predicate sub-queries can only be used in a filter in Spark.

The following works in a locally recreated copy of your data:

```
select orderid, custid, case when existing_customer is null then 'N' else 'Y' end existing_customer
          from (select o.orderid, o.custid, c.custid existing_customer
                from orders o
                left join customer c
                 on c.custid = o.custid)
```

Here's how it works with recreated data:

```
def textToView(csv: String, viewName: String) = {
   spark.read
  .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "true")
  .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "true")
  .option("delimiter", "|")
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(csv.split("\n")).toDS)
  .createOrReplaceTempView(viewName)
}

textToView("""id | custid
              1  | XYZ
              2  | UVW""", "customer")

textToView("""orderid | custid
              12345   | XYZ
              34566   | XYZ
              68790   | MNP
              59876   | QRS
              15620   | UVW""", "orders")

spark.sql("""
          select orderid, custid, case when existing_customer is null then 'N' else 'Y' end existing_customer
          from (select o.orderid, o.custid, c.custid existing_customer
                from orders o
                left join customer c
                 on c.custid = o.custid)""").show
```

Which returns:

```
+-------+------+-----------------+
|orderid|custid|existing_customer|
+-------+------+-----------------+
|  59876|   QRS|                N|
|  12345|   XYZ|                Y|
|  34566|   XYZ|                Y|
|  68790|   MNP|                N|
|  15620|   UVW|                Y|
+-------+------+-----------------+
```